# how to register japanese font in @react-pdf/render

Tags: pdf, fonts, react-pdf

I'm using @react-pdf/render to display Japanese to pdf file. I don't know how to change  font Oswald to font NotosanJP. How can i get the src for font i wanna. Thank You very much.

```
Font.register({
  family: 'oswald',
  src: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/oswald/v13/Y_TKV6o8WovbUd3m_X9aAA.ttf'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the `tff` file for the font and then import it as a variable i.e.:

```
 import font from "src";
```

Then use that font in your source file i.e.:

```
 Font.register({
   family: 'NotosanJP',
   src: font
 })
```